# Sqlite data with desktop application

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, desktop-application

I am creating java desktop application. I have created exe of my jar file using exe4j. Now i am binding my sqlite database with my exe using easy binder software. But when i run my application the data is getting saved properly but when i rerun the application the data is not there which i have saved before. Please help

I have tried using the specific path i.e. stored the sqlite db file at specific location, it is working but it is not secure as any one can open the file.

I need to embed the database along with my application but the database is not saving the data when i rerun my application.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your data is only getting temporarily stored because SQLite is using a transient in-memory database due to the fact that it can't find the specified database. Please specify what version of SQLite driver you are using, as well as an example of its use in your code.

Is you are worried about the security of someone accessing the database, then you may wish to consider another database besides SQLite.

Comment: My code for calling the db is as follows

Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:demo_system.db");

Can i store the db file in my resources folder and access the file.
I tried storing the file in resources folder but when jar in exe format i am not able to fetch the resources path

Comment: It doesn't appear that Java is finding your database. Are you sure it's on the classpath? After building your project, run it and execute the database write. Then, look through the dist folder until you find a "demo_system.db" file that contains nothing. This is where java is looking for your database.

Comment: SQLite should create a database if one is not found, thus there should be an empty database in the project somewhere. Save _your_ database there.